# Why is my Visualforce PDF footer just off-center?

Tags: visualforce, css, html, pdf

I have a Visualforce PDF page with a footer section, but this isn't centered - it is just off center and I can't figure out why. What do I need to do to get it centered?

[image]

My CSS classes contain this:
PageStyle:

```
.logo{max-width:200px;height:auto;}
.aleft{text-align:left;}
.aright{text-align:right;}
.acenter{text-align:center}
.ajustify{text-align:justify}
.bordertop{border-top:1px solid black}
.borderbottom{border-bottom:1px solid black}
```

VFfonts:

```
.labelfont{font-size:11pt;font-weight:800;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.labelfontsmall{font-size:8pt;font-weight:800;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.textfont{font-size:11pt;font-weight:500;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.valuefont{font-size:11pt;font-weight:500;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-align:right;}
.headerfont{font-size:14pt;font-weight:600;font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.mainheaderfont{font-size:24pt;font-weight:800;font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.subheaderfont{font-size:16pt;font-weight:800;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.notefont{font-size:8pt;font-weight:500;font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
```

And my actual VF page:

```
<apex:page id="certificatePDF" applyBodyTag="false" controller="certificatePDFController" renderAs="PDF">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.VFFonts}"/>        
<apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.PageStyle}"/> 
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">

        @page {
            @top-center {
            content: element(header);
            }

            @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
            }

            size: 8.27in 11.69in;
            margin: 8mm;
            padding: 14mm;   
            color: #442865;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        p {
            margin-top: 0;
        }

        .footer {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            padding-top:5px;
            position: running(footer);
        }

        .grey{
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .sgreen{
            color: #c7d51e;
        }

        table, td, th {  
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="watermark">

    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="labelfontsmall borderbottom sgreen aleft" layout="block">
        <apex:image id="SyndexLogo" value="{!$Resource.sLogo}" height="auto" width="150px" alt="Syndex Logo"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>          
    <div style="height: 70px;" />
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="headerfont sgreen acenter" layout="block">
        My Certificate
    </apex:outputPanel>  
    <div style="height: 30px;" />
    <div>

        <table style="width:100%;margin:0;padding-right: 0px;">
            <tr>
                <td  colspan="4" class="labelfont grey acenter">Certificate Information</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelfont grey" style="width:20%">Reference</td>
                <td class="textfont" style="width:30%"></td>
                <td class="labelfont grey" style="width:25%">Certification Date</td>
                <td class="textfont" style="width:25%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, date, d MMMM yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!reportDate}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelfont grey" style="width:20%">Type</td>
                <td class="textfont" style="width:30%"></td>
                <td class="labelfont grey" style="width:25%">Expiry Date</td>
                <td class="textfont" style="width:25%">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0, date, d MMMM yyyy}">
                        <apex:param value="{!reportDate}" /> 
                    </apex:outputText>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
    </div>        
    <div style="height: 70px;" />
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="labelfont" layout="block">
        FINANCIAL CERTIFICATION
    </apex:outputPanel>          
    <div style="height: 20px;" />
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="textfont" layout="block">
        Eum velit sanctus an, mea id nisl adipisci. Volumus accusata mnesarchum eu sea, debet patrioque has cu. Sit ea quem dicta partem, vide detraxit ei his, in ius diceret dissentias reprehendunt. Ex esse tantas definiebas sed. Pri oblique percipit ne, ne adipisci petentium disputando vis. In sed iuvaret alterum.
        <br/>
        <br/>
        Sit veri essent id, vel noluisse inimicus et, ius an enim dicunt. Convenire adipiscing adversarium qui et, ea graeci quaeque eloquentiam sed.

        <p style="margin:5px 20px 5px 20px">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, error facilisi atomorum sit ei. Paulo legere scribentur no duo, his ad alii unum 
            quaestio. Epicurei suavitate duo et. Possit singulis vix an, te quis dico conclusionemque has. Cum facer eirmod 
            an, vim cu velit munere.
        </p>
    </apex:outputPanel>          
    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="labelfontsmall footer bordertop acenter sgreen">
        My Limited, 100 Main Street, Auckland, New Zealand<br/>
        www.mywebsite.com
    </apex:outputPanel>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Played around some more and turns out this change is what fixed it in the CSS:

```
        <style type="text/css" media="print">

        @page {
            @top-center {
            content: element(header);
            }

            @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
            }

            size: 8.27in 11.69in;

            margin: 3cm 2.5cm;
        }

        .header {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 10px;
            position: running(header);
        }

        .footer {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            position: running(footer);
        }

        .grey{
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        .sgreen{
            color: #c7d51e;
        }

        table, td, th {  
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
```